# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '14:24:56 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I dont understand this error, guys please help me. why I am getting this error.. Is there something wrong in my query?

```
SELECT tblprojects.id AS lid,
tblemployees.FirstName,
tblemployees.LastName,
tblemployees.EmpId,
tblemployees.id,
tblemployees.Gender,
tblemployees.Phonenumber,
tblemployees.EmailId,
tblprojects.Project,
tblprojects.Cur_Date,
tblprojects.Hours,
tblprojects.Description,
tblprojects.PostingDate,
tblprojects.Status,
tblprojects.AdminRemark,
tblprojects.AdminRemarkDate 
FROM
tblprojects 
JOIN tblemployees ON tblprojects.empid=tblemployees.id 
WHERE tblprojects.empid=1 AND tblprojects.PostingDate=2019-05-20 14:24:56
```

i want the project name with that date submitted by employee

Comment: Add `' '` at your date. `AND tblprojects.PostingDate='2019-05-20 14:24:56'`

Comment: Thanks, Now I have it.

Comment: But its not working in my program.

Comment: SELECT tblprojects.id as lid,tblemployees.FirstName,tblemployees.LastName,tblemployees.EmpId,tblemployees.id,tblemployees.Gender,tblemployees.Phonenumber,tblemployees.EmailId,tblprojects.Project,tblprojects.Cur_Date,tblprojects.Hours,tblprojects.Description,tblprojects.PostingDate,tblprojects.Status,tblprojects.AdminRemark,tblprojects.AdminRemarkDate from tblprojects join tblemployees on tblprojects.empid=tblemployees.id where tblprojects.empid=:lid and tblprojects.PostingDate=':PostingDate'

Comment: Is it working in MySQL?

Comment: Yes its worked i just change :PostingDate to $PostingDate